# WPF. Button in DataGrid Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, button

How to change Button Visibility in DataGrid if specific text is in row cell?

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Click="ConfirmEvent"
                Visibility="if (SensorValueText == "qwerty") Visible"
                Margin="0"  
                Content="" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                IsEnabled="True"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A datatrigger would look something like:

```
    <DataTemplate>
        <Button Click="ConfirmEvent">
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SensorValue}" Value="qwerty">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I see you are using events there.
The next problem you are likely to find is working out which row the user clicked the button on.
Bear in mind pretty much all wpf teams use a pattern called MVVM.
With this, you would bind a command.
That would either go in a viewmodel used per row - and you'd copy data to and back from each viewmodel.
Or
You could put the command in a parent viewmodel which is used as the datacontext of the window and pass the row as a parameter to that.
A sample that illustrates these techniques is:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/WPF-Command-and-Row-in-84635e1a

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you create a new Converter class?

```
class TextToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.ToString() == "someValue")
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And then in the xaml, you can call the converter:

```
<local:TextToVisibilityConverter x:Key="TextConverter"/>
```

Then, you can call it inside the button:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Visibility="{Binding SomeText, Converter={StaticResource 
      TextToVisibilityConverter}}....>
</DataTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Feel free to ask if there are any follow-ups.

Comment: I'm not very strong yet about C#. I tryed to use your code. I changed `Converter={StaticResource    TextToVisibilityConverter}}` to `Converter={StaticResource TextConverter}}` It works! Thank you!

Comment: If you're comparing the entire value for a string then a datatrigger would work, It's only really if you need a partial match then you'd need a converter.

Comment: @Andy I could not apply datatrigger. How to I can use it?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I made a typo. It should be "..StaticResource TextConverter..". If you accept the answer, please do so. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score -2):

it's better to use trigger function from onChange() event (example : textbox.onChange())  and change the visibility (button.hidden = true/false) inside trigger function

Comment: No, it's not. This should be done e.g. via a Style-trigger or a bound property.